# how to serve pdf.js via Rails assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf.js

What is the right way of serving pdf.js via assets pipeline? As a quick solution I put the entire folder with all the pdf.js assets like pictures, fonts, scripts, styles, etc. into public folder, but I feel like there should be a better way.

I looked at a couple of GEMs available, but all of them seem to be outdated and contain 2-3 years old pdf.js in them.

Comment: For a big JS package like that, a gem is definitely the way to go.  If they're out of date, fork the best one and update it.  Otherwise, what you really need to do is split out the JS, CSS, images, etc into the individual `app/assets/XXX` directories in your Rails app.  No fun.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. This is exactly what I thought...